# Download Google Trends CSV Files (From AWS)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-crawler

Every month I run my script to download Google Trends CSV files for my research, and I have about 1000 search terms. I am aware of the famous "You've reached your quota limit, please try again later" error message hence I used the Mechanize python module in order to provide cookies. Here is my call:

```
 import mechanize # other imports omitted for simplicity 

 br = mechanize.Browser()

 cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
 br.set_cookiejar(cj)

 br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

 response = br.open('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https://www.google.com/')
 forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response)
 form = forms[0]
 form['Email'] = username
 form['Passwd'] = password
 response = br.open(form.click())

 Result = br.open("http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?q=SearchTerm&export=1") 
 CSVcontent = csv.reader(StringIO(Result.read()))
```

In my actual script, I have a sleep time specification which varies from 1 to 5 seconds.

However, with these methods, I can only download around 350 CSV files at a time. After the run, even if I re-run my script on a different AWS instance (different region, with the same Google account credentials), I can only download 2 terms before my quota limit runs out.

I've also tried to re-run the script on the same instance, with used but different Google credentials, but same thing happened (2 CSV downloads only).

The worst thing is that, even after a month, I can still only download 2 CSV files each day with Google credentials that I used in my script a (couple of) month(s) ago.

Hence I guess Google is monitoring user downloads on both IP address level as well as user account level, and they flag accounts that download too much.

> My Questions:
>
> Is there anyone can tell me whether there is a paid service or API
>   that is quota limit free?
>
> Or is there a way to bypass Google's monitoring (by using Tor or other
>   methods)? But even with Tor I'll still need Google account credential
>   right?
>
> Is there a way to download Google Trends data without a
>   username/password (so I can auto-scale with AWS as each IP address can
>   at least download 2 CSV files)?

Any help and out-of-the-box thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Is there a way to download Google Trends data without a username/password

Yes, there is a way to get your data without having to login (I am in testing on it now and it is looking good but it's also a secret I can not share as I do not what to loose it).

I can share that I downloaded between 3,000 to 5,000 files over the weekends almost the same way you do it, and I do it every weekend. ( 2 IP's , 2 ID's)

Ihe only secret i can give is do not hammer Google. If you hammer them there system will cut you off

I found a 1.5 to 2 min break will help you.

Look at it this way: 24 hours in a day, that's 1440 mins.  If you pull a file every 2 mins that's 720 files a day.

And they wont cut you off also if you put a random time function in, they can not tell if it is you or a script.

> only download 2 CSV files each day with Google credentials that I used in my script a (couple of) month(s) ago

It will reset if you do not use the account for a week or so; also, if you can renew you ip that will help.

Comment: Hi jnovo/Skittles:

thank you so much for your answer, it's great to know that other people out there are doing the same thing as I am.

I do have a random time function, but it only varies from 1 sec to 5 sec. I will definitely try the 1.5~2 min break. Also I appreciate your help on how to recover a blocked account.

When times come and you feel comfortable, I'd be very much interested in looking at your "secret" method. Alas your help is deeply appreciated!

In the future if you'd like to reach out, you may email to: hcapitaltest@gmail.com, it's one of the accounts I use for downloading :-)

Comment: Please share the way if there is one!